# Is it necessary to allocate multiple channels at the same time window?

Tags: communication, wireless, telecommunications

Let a channel allocation system is to be deployed to allocate unlicensed frequency spectrum to a set of access points.

The system performs channel sharing in time-domain.

Let an access point, say N1, demands 2 channels (frequency slots), say C1, C2 to operate.

I need to ask, is it possible for the system to allocate C1 and C2 to N1 in different time-window? In other words, is it ok if the system allocates C1 in time T1 and C2 in time T2? where T1 and T2 represent some time window in a scheduled repetition period.

I am asking such a question because someone said "it is not practical that you schedule an access point in different time window." He said, "if an access point is allocated multiple channels then it needs all those channels at the same time to operate. We cannot schedule it in different time window"

I need your help to clear this concept. Moreovre if there is no such compulsion can you please tell me some reference so that I can use that reference in the argument.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why can not share the channels in the way you propose, as long as all your devices are synchronised in time so they know when to start and/or stop using a particular frequency band then there is nothing stopping you doing what you propose.

Comment: Dear KillaKem thanks for your comment. I agree with you but, the issue is that I need some reference for it. I need so because I got a comment from a reviewer on my paper. I want to use the reference in my response to the comment. Thanks

Comment: Code and frequency multiplexing are very well documented and there are many issues that deal with those issues, google "frequency multiplexing". The question of practicality depends on the system as a whole, is there something about the technology being used that makes multiplexing in the way you propose impractical?